# Creating containers for paragraphs

Tags: graphics, diagrams, scientific-notation

I would like to know how can I create a container symbol at the beginning and end of paragraphs.

Here the precise example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I use the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{mypara}%
  {\tikz\draw (0,0)|-(1em,1em);\kern -0.8em}%
  {\kern -1em\tikz[baseline]\draw (0em, -0.2em)-|(1em, 0.8em);}
\begin{document}

\begin{mypara}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mypara}

{\small
\begin{mypara}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mypara}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can we make it work for footnotes?

Answer (score 2):

Three approaches without tikz, one using `amssymb` package symbols  and two that do not need any package (the others that are used in the MWE are only for the display convenience).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip1em
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
% need  amssymb
\def\beginpar{\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Large$\ulcorner$\kern-0.2em}}}
\def\endpar{ \makebox[0pt][r]{~\raisebox{-3pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Large$\lrcorner$}}\par}
\beginpar \lipsum[1][1-2]\endpar
\beginpar \lipsum[3][1-2]\endpar
\newcolumn % without any package
\def\beginpar{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Large$\lceil$\kern-.25em}\;}
\def\endpar{\makebox[0pt]{\space\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Large$\rfloor$}}\par}
\beginpar \lipsum[1][1-2]\endpar
\beginpar \lipsum[3][1-2]\endpar
\newcolumn % also without any package
\def\beginpar{\raisebox{.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{\leavevmode\rlap{\begin{tabular}[b]{|p{.2ex}}\hline\\[-1ex]\end{tabular}}}\;}
\def\endpar{\;\llap{\raisebox{1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}[c]{p{.2ex}|}\\[1pt]\hline\end{tabular}}}\par}
\beginpar \lipsum[1][1-2]\endpar
\beginpar \lipsum[3][1-2]\endpar
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we make it work for footnotes?

Comment: There are nothing incompatible  in the three types of macros  to use `\footnote{ \beginpar ...\endpar}`  but you will want to play with the lengths and spaces to look better with a  smaller font with different indentation and a number on the left margin.